# How to call a function from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, loops, insert

Using SQL Server 2008, please advise if it is possible to do the following:
I have 2 Tables, the first is Customers:

```
     ID Name    FunToCalc
    ====== ======= ============
       1    John     Fun1()
       2    Saad     Fun2()
       3    Ali  Fun2()
```

the second is Bills:

```
      ID    BillNo    CustomerID     Value
    ====== =======    ==========    =========
       1    B1        1 
       2    B2        2     
       3    B3        3
```

I want to make 
"Insert into Bills Select from Customers" where The "Value" column 
is the return value of the Functions found in "FunToCalc"
Can I do that in one statment (Insert into select from)
Or I have to make it using "while loop" on Customers Table 
to return the value from the function 
and insert it into Bills Table

I hope that I explained what I want clearly

Comment: It might work with a dynamic SQL script. What DB engine are you using?

Comment: I think its possible. So just to clarify is the Bills table already populated with a NULL for value? And what actual RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write the select statement, you can call the function 
This is an example for using function in select for oracle
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5173758137186

google on this and you will find a lot of examples

Comment: I searched a lot but I didn't found what I want , the trick is how to call the function from the first table and set it's return value to the second table with out using variable

Comment: you will use something like the following:
    INSERT INTO table2
    (column_name1, column_name2)
    SELECT column_nameA, yourFunction(column_nameB)
    FROM table1;